# Add observer for nested properties

Tags: objective-c, observers

When using something like...

```
[_queueController addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"currentPlayer.currentTrack" options:0 context:nil];
```

..., then only changes of `currentTrack` are observed as long as currentPlayer doesn't change.

My first idea to fix for this problem would be to observe `currentPlayer` and re-add the observer on every change. But is there any better solution for this problem?

Comment: this varies on how the user uses the app, it may change on every track but also may never change

Comment: @TReddy: does it matter? KVO itself shouldn't be affected by the frequency with which the key changes, and performance is a separate discussion from this one (which is "it doesn't work at all"), as far as I understand it.

Comment: @Tim Yes, that is what I am meaning. I can not understand the connection to the frequency of key changes too.